# Drupal's Taxonomy access permissions - setup help needed

Tags: drupal, permissions, taxonomy

trying to setup drupal's taxonomy module (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) to administer access to specific categories.

i have two categories of users (two kind of roles). all i'm trying to do is to setup that one have access to some category, and other not.

i did made proper(?) changes in admin/user/taxonomy_access and (ie.) admin/user/taxonomy_access/edit/7, but still user from other group can access to the content that should be forbidden for them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rebuild permissions (URL: /admin/content/node-settings/rebuild). If you set up the permissions correctly, this should fix your problem. I would also clear all caches, just to be sure.

Comment: tnx, it did help! but still user that have no right to access that category still can see link in menu. it is possible to hide?

Comment: Menu items, for which you don't have permission, should not appear in a menu. Try clearing the cache again.

Answer (score 0):

I would also try to rebuild permissions. If you are using Drupal 7, the Rebuild Permissions link has been moved. It can be found at `/admin/reports/status/rebuild`

You can also navigate to Reports -> Status report and the link is under the Node Access Permissions row.